# Usage of "vacation"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, usage

How can say to someone that I cannot take a vacation on a specific month?
I came up with some phrases but I'm not sure if any of them are grammatically correct.

- I don't have a vacation in July
- I can't take a vacation in July
- I don't have a holliday in July

Also, am I allowed to use *vacation* instead of *holliday*? I've been told that this is common in the UK but I'd like to confirm that.

Comment: American or British English?

Comment: @Laurel, american or both if possible

Comment: In Canada, we use both *holiday* and *vacation*, and I would say "I don't have any holiday (or vacation) time in July", if I'm out of time to take, or "I can't take a holiday (or vacation) in July", if my employer simply won't permit it even though I have time available.  "I don't have a holiday (or vacation) in July" means, to me, that I simply don't have one scheduled then.

Comment: Unless there is an unusual local spelling that I am not aware of, I think 'Holliday' is a name. It is 'holiday' that means time off work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Vacation time" can be thought of as a bulk quantity like sugar.  So I would say in my idiomatic American English, "I can't take vacation in July."